# Is there a way to find HRESULT C definition by value?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, com

I'm curious if there's a resource to look up HRESULT error codes C definitions by value?

For instance, if I have `0x80004002` where can I get `E_NOINTERFACE` definition for it?

Comment: There are descriptions for most error codes in `winerror.h`, also `FormatMessage` can sometimes return a plain text error message.

Comment: If you mean programmatically, FormatMessage is a good bet. If you just want the description of the error, the "Error Lookup" utility in your Debug menu does wonders. I'm not aware of any OS-provided utility that, given an error code, will return the E_ macro name.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/05/14/a-list-of-common-hresult-error-codes.aspx

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, thanks. That's what I was looking for. Ideally it'd be a reverse of what "Error lookup" utility does for VS. Is there such a tool? Otherwise Lundin's link has the right page and one needs to use web browser's "Find" option to locate the definition.

Comment: And, no `FormatMessage` won't do what I need here. It may (note emphasis on "may") retrieve a localized (or human-readable) definition of an error. But I'm looking for C definition itself, or `E_NOINTERFACE` in my example above. And no, it doesn't have to be programmatically.

Comment: Load up `winerror.h` and do a Ctrl-F for 0x80004002.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yeah, that's another manual way of doing it. (Except sometimes the code can be broken down into HRESULT components, in which case a text search for the full code value would not work.)

Comment: What you are looking for cannot exist, since there is no fixed set of values. COM objects can define their own [HRESULT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088.aspx) values, that need not be available as symbolic constants.

Comment: This online tool (disclaimer: I wrote it) does it: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0x80004002 and the reverse https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=E_NOINTERFACE

Comment: @SimonMourier: Where do you take those values from? It would be helpful to explain that on SO instead of just posting a black-box solution.

Comment: There is a whole explanation in the site "How does it work?" "Faq", etc.

Comment: @IInspectable And yet, if you provide e.g. `0x80040203`, which is a custom error code (`FACILITY_ITF`), "the system" will give you some error message (in this case, `EVENT_E_QUERYSYNTAX`, "A syntax error occurred trying to evaluate a query string"). Is there a single "default" COM component that is used as a lookup source for this error message, even though it's a custom one?

Comment: @gse *"if you provide e.g. `0x80040203` \[...\], "the system" will give you"* - Provide the value to whom? What is *"the system"* here?

Comment: @sim Could you change the Magic Number Database UI so that the search field is focused automatically on the main/landing page? That's the only issue I have with an otherwise immensely helpful tool.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I had the context in my head only. Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/q/69370099/11683 where VBA/VB6 upon `Err.Raise &h80040203` will retrieve that message from somewhere. I was wondering whether there was a solid principle behind this, or the component containing the textual message is selected basically at random.

Comment: @gse If you look at the [layout of COM error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/structure-of-com-error-codes) you'll see that the `C` bit (customer bit) isn't set for this value. That means it is a value defined by Microsoft, allowing them to deal with lookup however they want. At a guess it is what `FormatMessage` returns when you are using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` flag.

Comment: @IInspectable But as that very page explains, the `C` flag is reserved (not for us to use), and the way you declare a custom error is by using Facility = `FACILITY_ITF`? Which is further enforced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/codes-in-facility-itf).

Comment: @gse It is only reserved in that it cannot be 0 for customer-defined error codes (see [HRESULT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a)). The [message compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/message-compiler--mc-exe-) has a dedicated option to set that bit. I doubt that any of this is relevant in context of VBA/VB6, which probably just implements the `IErrorInfo` interface.

Comment: @IInspectable Same error message appears in .NET with `Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(0x80040203)`. Also that `C` situation then means that no VBA custom codes are valid at all because they are not going to have that bit set with vbObjectError being 0x80040000. Did the requirement to have the `C` bit set exist from very beginning?

Comment: @gse I don't know whether or when the customer bit was introduced, though given that COM and Windows NT were introduced at the same time, I'm pretty sure that Don Box did know about the [NTSTATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/87fba13e-bf06-450e-83b1-9241dc81e781) layout. As for `FACILITY_ITF` specifically, it doesn't really matter whether a client follows the customer bit contract. The rules are simple in this case: The interface is responsible for producing the error information.

Comment: @IInspectable - seemed a reasonable request :-) done.

Comment: @sim That is awesome, thanks!